How can I bypass a expired apt-key
How can I bypass a expired key to install MongoDB 4.0? I keep getting these errors saying the key is expired.

Does this answer your question? "GPG error:The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED"

"bypass" of a basic safety and security measure seems unwise.
